# Use USB stick with file on it to select GRUB 2 entry

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

I have a machine which has Windows and Ubuntu 20.04 on it. The active partition (first boot item in BIOS) is the one where Ubuntu is installed on, and I've manually entered entries to GRUB to have Windows as a selection to boot into, which is set as the default.

I would like to be able to use a USB stick (or maybe better a SD-Card) in order to change the default selection. If it is inserted, it should boot into Ubuntu (the first entry), if not, then it should use the default selection (the third entry, Windows).

Would I need to (somehow, I wouldn't know how) install/copy/dd GRUB onto the USB-Stick/SD-Card and select it to be the first item in the BIOS's boot order, with a fallback to Ubuntu's partition, which is currently the first in the boot order?

Or is there (hopefully) a tool where I can just place a file on the Stick/Card which is then read by GRUB?

---

Update: I've been checking out the GRUB config files and noticed that there is one file called `/boot/grub/grubenv` which has an entry named `next_entry=`. This line exists because I sometimes used `sudo grub-reboot 0` in order to *reboot* into Ubuntu. If I execute `sudo grub-reboot 0` then this line changes to `next_entry=0`.

I am now thinking about modifying `/etc/default/grub/00_header` to check if a certain USB device is connected, and if it is, that it then either writes `next_entry=0` into the `grubenv` file, or that I add some code which just sets the necessary variables similar to how `next_entry=0` is doing it.

So now my issue is that I don't know what actions can be performed in `00_header`, eventually using `curl` to fetch the variable would be perfect, but I guess that at that point no networking is present and that curl is not a recognized command.

How can I debug/get to learn GRUB to see what is doable in this file without risking of damaging the system?

I'm currently thinking about using a clean VM with a Snapshot into which I can revert into if something goes wrong, in order to gain some insights. But maybe a hint or two from experts here would have a lot of value to me.

Comment: Grub 2 config can probably do this with a custom config.  It's essentially turing complete and knows about partitions so it can probably mount some FSs explicitly.  Maybe the FS would be limited to EXT or EFI(FAT16/32)?  Integrating it with the distro's automatic grub config system might be another matter.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS installs? Active partition with BIOS is only for Windows, grub does not use it. But with UEFI the boot,esp flags really set the very long GUID to make a FAT32 partition as UEFI bootable. And ESP is used by both Windows & Ubuntu. If BIOS install Windows boot loader to MBR and install grub to flash drive, or MMC card, if BIOS will boot from MMC, some do not. If you just install grub to flash drive, you probably have to create your own grub.cfg file. But can start by copying from your install version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you abort the boot process at the GRUB 2 selection menu and drop into the shell, you will be able to list the connected devices by executing the `ls` command.

In my case the USB stick was `(hd0,msdos1)`.

First I modified the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file so that it includes the following:

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
# =================== BEGIN MODIFICATION ===================
if [ -s (hd0,msdos1)/grub_boot_config ]; then
  set next_entry=0;
fi
# =================== END MODIFICATION ===================
if [ "${initrdfail}" = 2 ]; then
   set initrdfail=
elif [ "${initrdfail}" = 1 ]; then
   ...
```

where `next_entry=0` is what `$prefix/grubenv` would be setting if I had run `sudo grub-reboot 0`.

This works, but it doesn't survive a kernel upgrade, since this rebuilds `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Then I modified `/etc/grub.d/00_header` by adding the following:

```
cat << EOF
if [ -s \$prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
EOF
# =================== BEGIN MODIFICATION ===================
cat << EOF
# =================== BEGIN MODIFICATION ===================
if [ -s (hd0,msdos1)/grub_boot_config ]; then
  set next_entry=0;
fi
# =================== END MODIFICATION ===================
EOF
# =================== END MODIFICATION ===================
cat <<EOF
if [ "\${initrdfail}" = 2 ]; then
   set initrdfail=
elif [ "\${initrdfail}" = 1 ]; then
   ...
```

and issued `sudo update-grub`, which then generated `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

The result is that if a USB stick is plugged in and it contains the file `grub_boot_config` (it can be empty) in the root, then `(hd0,msdos1)/grub_boot_config` will succeed and set `next_entry=0`.

Next step of improvement would be to include `0` (or whichever menu item should be booted into) in the file, and have the script read it and set `next_entry` to it, as well as make it search for this file on every drive, not just `(hd0,msdos1)`.

In any case, it turns out that `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` is very resilient towards typos, so that it is unlikely that you break your system by doing these modifications (this I tested with a clean VM).

Answer (score 0):

There used to be a software called Multisystem. I see it's still around. It's generally a software that lets you install multiple distros onto a USB stick. The way you could use it (and I've used it) is to use it to boot to grub (USB flash drive's grub). A newer tool I see is called Ventoy, but I've not used it. Looks like it has the same approach. Basically, I had GRUB in my pocket. Otherwise I used to boot into Windows. I did not have grub installed (on purpose) and I was also dual booting, using the USB stick to boot into Debian. There are cleaner ways to do this, but these would be easier I think.